# Chakra UI, How to align component to the left?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, alignment

I have this drawer example. Within `drawerExample.js` there's a Chakra component called   `<DrawerCloseButton />` I've been trying to wrap this component with `<Flex>` it wont seem to budge.

How can I render this component on the left side as I would like to change it into a back button

[image: Edit chakra-UI drawer as sidebar (forked)]

Answer (score -2, accepted):

`<CloseButton />` provided more flexibility so I have used this instead

Answer (score 0):

Just change `placement` right to left in drawerExample.js

Here is my [code](https://codesandbox.io/embed/chakra-ui-drawer-as-sidebar-forked-46nuq?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

Comment: I want to move the X button from right to left not the actual drawer

Comment: Ok let me check

Answer (score -1):

You can align images or sources by giving the source a class, for example

<img class="photo" src=photo.png" alt="A photo">

so you can give the source a class and go to css and give

.photo {
align: left
}

or you can use

.photo {
float: left
}

Hope it works!